# Need help with CAML in CQWP

Tags: caml-query, content-query-web-part

I tried to implement a CQWP web part that could show me all the checked-out files following this guide: http://www.the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Further-Customise-CQWP-to-Display-Draft-and-Checked-Out-Pages-By-User.aspx. I got a 'There is a problem with the query that this Web Part is issuing. Check the configuration of this Web Part and try again.' error

I figure I am probably making a noob mistake here, so please feel free to point fingers and laugh as long as you help me solve this.

btw, full code below :

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
        <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
        <property name="Title" type="string">All Draft Documents</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
        <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
        <property name="MediaPlayerStyleSource" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" />
        <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Asc</property>
        <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string">User</property>
        <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue3" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue2" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterDisplayValue1" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
        <property name="DataMappings" type="string">Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|Description:{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700},_Comments,Note;|LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|ImageUrl:{B9E6F3AE-5632-4b13-B636-9D1A2BD67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|</property>
        <property name="ListGuid" type="string" />
        <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="FilterValue1" type="string" />
        <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
        <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
        <property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string" />
        <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string">Modified,Description</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
        <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="Height" type="string" />
        <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Default" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterType1" type="string" />
        <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">Default</property>
        <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" />
        <property name="WebUrl" type="string">/</property>
        <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
        <property name="Width" type="string" />
        <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="PlayMediaInBrowser" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef ID="{fdc3b2ed-5bf2-4835-a4bc-b885f3396a61}"&gt;&lt;/FieldRef&gt;&lt;Value Type="Number"&gt;3&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt; 
        </property>
        <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
        <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
        <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Modified,DateTime;CheckoutUser,User;</property>
        <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="MainXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
        <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren2" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">And</property>
        <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
        <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
        <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren1" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string" />
        <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
        <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
        <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
        <property name="Filter2IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
        <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
        <property name="Filter3IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="SampleData" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
        <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
        <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">And</property>
        <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
        <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string" />
        <property name="Xsl" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
        <property name="ListName" type="string" />
        <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Filter1IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Use to display a dynamic view of content from your site on a web page</property>
        <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FilterField1" type="string" />
        <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">850</property>
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FilterIncludeChildren3" type="bool">False</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Embedded CAML Query:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef ID="{fdc3b2ed-5bf2-4835-a4bc-b885f3396a61}"></FieldRef>
        <Value Type="Number">3</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/>
</OrderBy>
```

Answer (score 1):

From that guide (and your question) it looks like this line in your code ("All Draft Documents"):

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef ID="{fdc3b2ed-5bf2-4835-a4bc-b885f3396a61}"&gt;&lt;/FieldRef&gt;&lt;Value Type="Number"&gt;3&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;</property>
```

Should be this line ("All Checked Out Documents"):

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">&lt;Where&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/&gt;&lt;/IsNotNull&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;</property>
```

It could be that the field referred to by ID in the first query isn't present, for whatever reason.

Comment: I'd recommend using the CDATA elements to escape your XML, rather than encoding it, as it keeps it readable, and makes problem solving tasks such as this a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: @James: What? I had to press Ctrl+C Ctrl+V *twice* to make that answer; I think that's work enough. ;)

Comment: Lol Stuart, was intended at the original poster ;)

Comment: That's what I originally used, but I got errors so I swapped stuff around to see if that would fix it.

Comment: You mean the field of Modified date?

Comment: @Kitler: I'm afraid I'm not sure what the GUID refers to; I'm just guessing the cause based on the difference in the CAML queries. If the query isn't working after following the guide, swapping in an entirely different query won't produce the same results. I'd advise posting a question for the error you get when using the original query.

Comment: Try using the U2U CAML Builder client; it helped me narrow down issues with my query. Plus I posted questions here and the good people helped me a lot :)